# Hide your IP when connecting remotely

Tags: ip, hide, putty, tor, terminal-emulator

I was wondering how some people is able to hide their IP when they connect remotely to a server for example. I'm connecting frequently to a linux server and I can see that when using the $who command, it shows from where is everyone connecting to the server, but sometimes it doesn't tell the IP nor the domain or anything, and somebody told me that is because he is hiding his ip using Tor or something similar. My question is: how can I hide my IP when I use a terminal emulator such as PuTTY so that the server doesn't knows my IP?

Comment: Perhaps the people who aren't showing an IP simply connect to the server locally? This is not likely to be on topic for Stack Overflow either way, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Connecting through Tor or some other mechanism to hide your true IP has nothing to do with why the `who` command doesn't show the IP or hostname.  Even if connected to an SSH server over Tor, it would show the Tor exit IP rather than nothing.

It may be like Pekka, said, they are connected locally, or another possibility is that their connection timed out and who still shows the login but they aren't actually connected.

If you want to run Putty over Tor to "hide" your IP from the server, just run Tor locally and configure Putty to use Tor as a SOCKS proxy.

You could also run [ProxyChains](http://proxychains.sf.net) to use Tor or other SOCKS proxies and then run either `proxychains putty` or `proxychains ssh user@host.org` to connect through the proxy which will prevent the server from seeing your actual IP.

**Configure PuTTY to use Tor**
[image: Configure PuTTY to use Tor]